# Get all materials inside an object for controlling mapping nodes with single var

Tags: python

For now i can control mapping by name of material but the problem is , all in this object material use mapping , exist a way to get all mapping node inside at material and controll all with my rot_var?
this object can 1 to multiple materials slots

i think but not work:

```
ob = context.object
rot_var = ###my variable(0 to 360)
   for s in ob.material_slots:
       if s.material.use_nodes:
           for n in s.material.node_tree.nodes:


                    mapping = n.get("Mapping")                                        
                    mapping.rotation[2] = radians(rot_var)
```

Edit: i find solution for Mapping:

```
for slots in ob.material_slots:
    for nodes in slots.material.node_tree.nodes:

        if nodes.type == 'MAPPING':    

            nodes.rotation[2] = radians(rot_var)
```

but inside i have 2 nodes "MixRGB" i not have idea to get  because same name of nodes and not have idea about name of MixRgb

Comment: Ok i find my solution is put name inside the node and to if statement : if nodes.name == "My personal name":

Comment: thats great. please add an answer so others may find the solution. As a new user you may have to wait 24hrs before you can add the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Wrote following in answer to this q. Noticed you sorted it out, thought I'd post anyway*

[image]

- Wrote a utility function to query an objects material nodes.
  `query_mat_nodes(ob, "type", 'MAPPING')` returns a list of all
  mapping type nodes.  `query_mat_nodes(ob, "name", "Frank")` returns a
  list of all nodes named "Frank" in the objects materials.
- Added a float property to the object with an update method to set all
  the mapping nodes on object to this property value.  Notice giving the
  property the `unit='ROTATION'` will display the value in the UI
  dependant on the setting for scene rotation unit in units panel. 
  (generally degrees is selected)  The property value will always be in
  radians.
- For want of a better place I tacked (prepended) `draw_prop` (a UI draw method) to the node space
  header to test.

Test script.

```
import bpy
from math import radians
def query_mat_nodes(ob, key, value):
    return set(n for s in ob.material_slots if s.material and s.material.use_nodes
            for n in s.material.node_tree.nodes if getattr(n, key, None) == value)


def update_map_nodes(self, context):
    for n in query_mat_nodes(self, "type", 'MAPPING'):
        n.rotation.z = self.map_rot

bpy.types.Object.map_rot = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
         min=0,
         max=radians(360),
         unit='ROTATION',
         update=update_map_nodes)

def draw_prop(self, context):
    self.layout.prop(context.object, "map_rot")

bpy.types.NODE_HT_header.prepend(draw_prop)
```

Comment: This is a good alternative!